# JasperReports Charts : Accessing Series expression 's Value in Customize() method

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I am using *JasperReports Server 5.0 professional Version*.

For one of the report, I am using Chart Customizer to customize the color of the bars. Evaluation Time is Report

In *iReport*, i have defined the Series expression as

```
 $F{form} + "(" + $V{month} + ")"
```

[image]

In customize method of *Java* file, i want to access above expressions' value which are

1-sep  , 2 - Oct, 3 -Jan , 4 -Feb

I have tried the following code to get Series values but no success.

```
  public JRCategorySeries[] categoryList = null ; 
  JRFillCategoryDataset  categoryDS  = (JRFillCategoryDataset)jasperChart.getDataset();
  categoryList = categoryDS.getSeries();

  SubCategoryAxis domainAxis = new SubCategoryAxis("");
  domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(0.05);

  for (int i = 0 ; i <categoryList.length -1 ; i++ ) {

    JRCategorySeries jrcategoryseries = categoryList[i];

    domainAxis.addSubCategory(jrcategoryseries.getSeriesExpression().getText());
  }
```

I need help in accessing series data point in customize method. I will appreciate your comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the dataset  from JFreeChart argument that is passed to the customize class.
Also to access the properties that you set for the chart in the jrxml can be accessed by the JRChart argument

Please try this

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

    // To access the dataset of the chart
     CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
     CategoryDataset catData = plot.getDataset();


  // to access the key property of chart <br/>
     String key = jasperChart.getKey();
}
```

Regards
Chandra